# How can an object access another objects data?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, header

Yet another question about my project for my university! We are creating a cash register program which has an inventory, both held in their own respective header files with their own classes and objects.

Here is our current iteration of our header files, thought it may be messy from debugging.

Inventory.h:

```
class inventory
{
    protected:
        vector <item> itemList;
        fstream infile;
    public:
        void printList();
        void fillInventory();
        void fileOpen();
};

class item
{
    protected:
        double price;
        string name;
        int amount;

        friend class inventory;
};
```

Register.h:

```
class cashRegister : protected inventory
{
    private:
        vector <int> userChoice;
        double total = 0;
    public:
        void input();
        void printReceipt();
        void calcTotal();
        const double getTotal();
};


void cashRegister::input()
{
    int temp;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "\nPlease select an item using the corresponding item number.\n=> ";
            cin >> temp;
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                throw(256);
            }
            else
            {
                if (temp == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 10)
                {
                    if (inventory.stockChecker(temp) == 1)
                    {
                        userChoice.push_back(temp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw(1);
                }
            }
            cout << "\n\n";
            printInventory();

        } while (true);
    }
    catch (int error)
    {
        cout << "Input error: " << error << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a value from 0 to 10 to select an item (-1 to exit).\n";
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        input();
    }
}
```

The problem here is once we pass ourselves into `Register.h`, we take user input then call the `printInventory` inventory method after every entry. But when we go to `printInventory` we no longer have the `itemList` data that the inventory object held.

Here is main.cpp for clarification on the objects:

```
#include"Inventory.h"
#include"Register.h"

int main()
{   
    inventory inv;

    inv.fileOpen();
    inv.fillInventory();
    inv.printInventory();

    cashRegister register1;

    register1.input();
    register1.calcTotal();
    register1.printReceipt();


}
```

Our object `inv` holds a vector of `item objects`, which has the data members `price amount name`. So when we create the `register1` object then try to print the inventory again, we now have an empty vector. How would I achieve being able to print the `inv` object's `itemList` or other data in general?

EDIT: Also to note I did try passing the inv object by reference and then calling the methods with that object. It did work but it felt awfully messy.

Comment: Pretending for a moment that the mystery class `inventoryManager` actually exists, this sounds like a `cashRegister` needs to *refer* to an existing `inventory` to know what's available. It need not (and likely should not) be by-value.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry that was supposed to be `inventory` not `inventoryManager`. Should I make a method in `inventory` to return `itemList` then store a local version of it in `cashRegister`? Or is there a better way to refer to the existing `itemList` in `inventory`?

Comment: I don't understand the inheritance design. Inheritance is about an "is a" extension. So, is a cashRegister inventory? if not why does it inherit?

Comment: @WhozCraig To be honest it was just apart of debugging. I wasn't sure how to access `inv` object's `itemList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data of `inv` from a `cashRegister` object; instead of passing the `inv` object as reference every time you use it's data, you may want to hold a pointer in `cashRegister` class. `inventory` class will have member functions for manupilating and accessing it's data. Therefore you will be able to access to same `cashRegister` from multiple `inventory` objects, easily doing operations on `cashRegister`. With this approach, you will just need to initialize your `cashRegister` class with a pointer to `inventory` class.

```
class inventory
{
public:
    void printList();
    void changeData();
    ...
};

class cashRegister
{
private:
    inventory* inv;
public:
    cashRegister(inventory *inv)
        :
        inv(inv)
    {}

    void printInventory()
    {
        inv->printList();
    }
    ...
};

int main()
{
    inventory inv;
    inv.fileOpen();
    inv.fillInventory();
    inv.printInventory();

    cashRegister register1(&inv);
    cashRegister register2(&inv);

    register1.input();
    register1.calcTotal();
    register1.printReceipt();
    register1.printInventory();

    register2.printInventory();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was teetering on the edge of using pointers and constructors to figure this out but I never combined the two. This makes a lot of sense to me I wasn't sure how to incorporate the pointer as using pointers with objects is still relatively new in our class. I'll implement this and see how it goes, my class is in 20 minutes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Okay so the only issue I have after developing more is when passing the object by a pointer to another class it says `no default constructor exists for <class>`. Though I thought it has a default constructor?  `cashRegister(inventory *inv :inv(inv){}`

Comment: Yeah, defining a custom constructor disables the compiler generated default constructor. But you can still enable it. `cashRegister() = default;` do this in your class publicly. But be aware that uninitialized members can cause problems. You probably wouldn't want to use default constructor in this specific example.

Comment: I tried `cashRegister(inventory *inv = {} ) : inv(inv){}` and it seemed to work.